# C# Running commands on MongoDB without connecting to specific database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to create a project which takes scripts and run them on the server. I am aware of the `RunCommand()` method of `MongoClient` class but this method requires me to connect to a database first, and what i need is for the script itself to eventually say which database i want to connect.

As an example, for script A - i want to create a script that takes all the database names and run a different script on each of those databases that start with the name "Prefix_".
And for script B - i want to run something on databse named "SomeDatabase".

What are my choices here? i have not found a single solution to this, other than running these on a mongo shell which its output cannot be trusted as its changing from each version.

Comment: I can't see any difficulties here. First get all databases on your server, then one string connection will work for all databases by passing the databases name. Then for each name you got, do whatever you want with it's own connection string

Comment: Im not sure if you dont understand what i need or i dont understand what youre saying. i need to be able to run a script that will do all these things i said above without knowing which database im using at development time. each script should connect to a database by some sort of rule (exact name, StartWith, etc) and then run some commands.

Comment: Yes, and by getting the databases name inside the server, you can execute whatever you want on specific database based on names you got before. Like :  `var databaseNames = server.GetDatabaseNames();`  make a connections string with a variable where it holds the database name, then do whatever you want !! isn't what you are looking for ?

Comment: sort of.. im looking for a way to do it within a given script, and not by the code

Comment: The point being that i want to create a proejct with Mongo-Driver, connect to the mongo database, and then run scripts that each of them can do operations on different databses